# Show a summary of all ratings

Tags: android, rating

I would like to include in my app a view of all ratings obtained by a specific object. This view has to be similar to Google Play ratings for apps (see image).

[image]

Is there something which can make it or i need code it manually?

Comment: Where do the ratings come from?

Comment: From my database

Comment: You can use this dedicated library https://github.com/Inconnu08/android-ratingreviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this chart Library: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Use the Type Horizontal-BarChart

Its a bit more complex than the chart making taught at school but that only will do your work.